# Apply function on dataframe Column to get several other columns Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I have a dataframe of thousands of rows. I want to apply a function on a single column in order to get other 7 columns and merge it to the dataframe.
Example of Dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'b':[4,5,6]})
    a   b
0   1   4
1   2   5
2   3   6
```

Example of Function. The function returns a dataframe

```
def function(x):
    return pd.DataFrame({'c':[x+2],'d':[x*2],'e':[x%2],'f':[x/2],'g':[x-2],'h':[x**2],'i':[x*x]})
```

What I try to do and get an error:

```
df[['c','d','e','f','g','h','i']] = df['a'].apply(lambda x: function(x))
```

Expected Output:

```
    a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   i
0   1   4   3   2   1   0.5 -1  1   1
1   2   5   4   4   0   1.0 0   4   4
2   3   6   5   6   1   1.5 1   9   9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need remove `[]` from `DataFrame` constructor and for processing values in column `a` like array use [`DataFrame.pipe`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html):

```
def function(x):
    return pd.DataFrame({'c':x+2,'d':x*2,'e':x%2,'f':x/2,'g':x-2,'h':x**2,'i':x*x})  


df[['c','d','e','f','g','h','i']] = df['a'].pipe(function)
#alternative
#df[['c','d','e','f','g','h','i']] = function(df['a'])
print (df)
   a  b  c  d  e    f  g  h  i
0  1  4  3  2  1  0.5 -1  1  1
1  2  5  4  4  0  1.0  0  4  4
2  3  6  5  6  1  1.5  1  9  9
```

Comment: For the specific example that I have given this solves the issue. However, I have a more complicated function where I use split(), to split the string and then process the list. This kind of method does not work as it takes the Series and gives an error AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'split'
Any hints?

Comment: @AliSultan - Not easy answering withut data, do you think `series.str.split()` like [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) ?

Comment: please check the link to the other question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66335102/applying-a-function-to-row-and-merge-the-resulted-columns-to-the-dataframe-panda

Comment: I added the code over there as it was difficult to add it here

Answer (score 1):

Return a `pd.Series` instead of a `pd.DataFrame`:

```
def function(x):
    return pd.DataFrame({'c':[x+2],'d':[x*2],'e':[x%2],'f':[x/2],'g':[x-2],'h':[x**2],'i':[x*x]}).loc[0]
```

Or,

```
def function(x):
    return pd.Series({'c':x+2,'d':x*2,'e':x%2,'f':x/2,'g':x-2,'h':x**2,'i':x*x})
```

Comment: This does not work. It gives an ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable